# Create date variable from time (Using SAS 9.3)

Tags: sas

Using SAS 9.3

I have files with two variables (Time and pulse), one file for each person. 
I have the information which date they started measuring for each person.
Now I want create a date variable whom change date at midnight (of course), how?

Example from text files:

```
23:58:02    106
23:58:07    105
23:58:12    103
23:58:17    98
23:58:22    100
23:58:27    97
23:58:32    99
23:58:37    100
23:58:42    99
23:58:47    104
23:58:52    95
23:58:57    96
23:59:02    98
23:59:07    96
23:59:12    104
23:59:17    109
23:59:22    105
23:59:27    111
23:59:32    111
23:59:37    104
23:59:42    110
23:59:47    100
23:59:52    106
23:59:57    114
00:00:02    123
00:00:07    130
00:00:12    130
00:00:17    125
00:00:22    119
00:00:27    116
00:00:32    122
00:00:37    116
00:00:42    119
00:00:47    117
00:00:52    114
00:00:57    114
00:01:02    110
00:01:07    103
00:01:12    98
00:01:17    98
00:01:22    102
00:01:27    97
00:01:32    99
00:01:37    93
00:01:42    97
00:01:47    103
00:01:52    96
00:01:57    93
00:02:02    93
00:02:07    95
00:02:12    106
00:02:17    99
00:02:22    102
00:02:27    96
00:02:32    93
00:02:37    97
00:02:42    102
00:02:47    101
00:02:52    95
00:02:57    92
00:03:02    100
00:03:07    95
00:03:12    102
00:03:17    102
00:03:22    109
00:03:27    109
00:03:32    107
00:03:37    111
00:03:42    112
00:03:47    113
00:03:52    115
```

Comment: Which language are you using for this? And what have you tried? Can you share some sample code?

Comment: Wops, sorry, forgot to tell you about the language. SAS. I have tried using retain and using counter. Also tried to increase date variable when lag in time variable goes from 23 to 0.

Comment: What are you actually doing?  Post what code you have now, so we can see how it fits in.

Answer (score 0):

Regex:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d*
```

See here for an example and play around with regex:
https://regex101.com/r/xF1fQ5/1

**EDIT:** and have a look at the SAS regex tip sheet: http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/datastep/perl_regexp/regexp-tip-sheet.pdf

Comment: If I have time for several days, how do that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Date lastDate = startDate;

List<NData> ListData = new ArrayList<NData>();
for(FileData fdat:ListFileData){
   Date nDate = this.getDate(lastDate,fdat.gettime());
   NData ndata= new NData(ndate,fdat.getMeasuring());
   LisData.add(nData);
   lastDate = nDate; 
 } 


. 
.
.
.
function Date getDate(Date ld,String time){

   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime(ld);
   int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
   int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1;
   int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
   int hourOfDay   = this.getHour(time); 
   int minuteOfHour = this.getMinute(time);

   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime lastDate = new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(ld)    
   org.joda.time.LocalDateTime newDate =  new org.joda.time.LocalDateTime(year,month,day,hourOfDay,minuteOfHour);

   if(newDate.isBefore(lastDate)){
     newDate = newDate.plusDays(1); 
   }
   return newDate.toDate();    

}
```

Comment: Is that JAVA? I'm trying to find my solution in SAS

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide a complete answer without sample code, but the SAS `lag()` function might be enough to do what you need.  Your data step would include lines like the following, assuming your time variable is called `time` and your date variable is called `date`:

```
retain date;
if time < lag(time) then date = date + 1;
```

This assumes you never have any 24 hour gaps (but it appears you'd have to assume that anyway).

This answer also assumes that the `time` field is already in a SAS time format.

Comment: This is exactly what I have tried. But the result is that only the first row after midnight get the new date. The row after that get the date before again :( Seems like the retain function doesn't work as I want.

Comment: Maybe you have a line assigning the initial value to "date"?  If so, you should preface it with a condition so that it only works on the first line, like this:  if \_n\_ = 1 then date = '01jan2014'd; for example.